# JavaScript Cluster worker not receiving messages

Tags: node.js, process, cluster-computing

I have a `NodeJS`(version 4.4.3) application on windows which runs as a server and forks a child process which does some processing of data. Due to the amount of data it has to handle it may not respond. I'd like to kill this task but don't know how to determine if this task has finished or is it hanging. I'm using *cluster-based* process management as follows. I hope it has all the pieces to manage signal handling.

In the real application, the child processes don't receive the shutdown message and I don't see their exit message.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
clients = 0,  // tracks number of active clients    
    workers = 1;  // configuration for number of worker tasks




/*
 * Code to perform cluster process management.
 */ 
if (cluster.isMaster)
{
  // create the workers.
  // Use env variables to dictate client or worker
  for (var i = 0; i < workers; i++)
  {
    cluster.fork({ "TYPE": 'worker'});
  }


  // Log that worker process has started
  cluster.on('online', function(worker) 
  {
    console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online.');
  });


  // Detect the death of a worker and log it
  var deadWorkers = 0; // tracks dead worker tasks
  cluster.on('death', function(worker)
  {
    deadWorkers++;
    console.log('worker ' + worker.pid + ' died.');

    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died.');

    if (deadWorkers === workers) 
    {
      console.log('Server is exiting as all workers are dead.')
      process.exit(0)
    }      
  });

  // Keep a track of clients connecting and disconnecting
  var deadClients = 0; // tracks number of dead clients   
  cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker)
  {
    deadClients++;
      console.log('worker ' + worker.pid + ' disconnected.');   
    console.log('number of dead clients: ' + clients);

    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' disconnected.');

    if (deadClients === clients) 
    {
      console.log('Server is exiting as all clients are dead.')
      process.exit(0)
    }
  });


  cluster.on('connect', function(worker)
  {
    clients++;
    console.log('number of clients: ' + clients);
  });


  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) =>
  {
    deadWorkers++;

      console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' exited with signal: ' + signal);

    if (deadWorkers === workers) 
    {
      console.log('Server is exiting as all clients are dead.')
      process.exit(0)
    }
  });


  // start the server task
  try
  {
    serverTask();
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    console.log("caught exception launching server task: " + err);
  }

}
else
{
  try
  {
    workerTask();
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    console.log("caught exception launching worker task when cluster is not a master: " + err);
  }

  if (cluster.isWorker)
  {  
    process.on('message', (msg) => 
    {
      console.log('worker received: ' + msg);

      if ('shutdown' === msg) 
      {
        var pid = process.pid;
        console.log('Worker ' + pid + ' is exiting...');
        process.disconnect();
        process.exit(0);
      }
    });
  }
}



function serverTask()
{
  console.log("server task")
}



function workerTask()
{
  console.log("worker task")
}


process.on('SIGINT', function() 
{  
  handleSignal('SIGINT');
});



function handleSignal(signal) 
{

  if(cluster.isMaster)
  {
      console.log("terminating due to signal: " + signal);

    for (var i in cluster.workers) 
    {
      console.log('killing workers ');
      cluster.workers[i].send('shutdown');
      cluster.workers[i].disconnect();
      timeout = setTimeout(() => { cluster.workers[i].kill(); }, 2000);
    }
    process.exit(signal);
  }  
}
```

Comment: A few quick comments: 
- If you want to use ES6 in your code, you should at least be using Node v6 and above. Is that possible in your scenario? Otherwise you could have a lot of errors just caused by lack of ES6 support. You can find a full matrix here: http://node.green. 
- This could be a Windows-specific issue since the Docs (even for Node v4) state there are issue with IPC on Windows. Have you tested on Linux?
- I would recommend using a transpiler like Babel for production Node with ES6. It's just a safer option for now and it's not hard to add to your build.

Comment: $ node server.js
server launched
worker 2493 is online
^Cterminating due to signal: SIGINT  
killing workers   
$ worker received: shutdown    
Worker 2493 is exiting...

Comment: Looks like I was away for long, the previous comment is an output from my linux VM. In fact, the target is embedded linux running NodeJS version 4.4.3. I followed your suggestion and it works on linux in my VM. That's great! Now the next step is to have the child process monitored based on a timer and then kill it. How can I do that? Thanks for the ideas or code if you have an example !.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I will post my slightly modified code-snippet shortly along with the answer I gave above. There are a few more suggestions for you in the code comments - I've marked them with a TODO tag.

To clarify your timer requirement: is that what you've mocked up using setTimeout in your snippet for the shutdown event? What is the purpose of killing a child process?

Comment: Actually, the child process is a worker and it processes data to produce a report using a template file. There can be issues in the template due to programming bugs. Once it happened that the process ate up all the heap and crashed. This is certainly not desired. What is more meaningful is to tell the process to exit cleanly by sending some signal if it did not respond for say N seconds. If the process is taking long to finish its job or respond than determined previously, it is better to make it exit cleanly and respond to the client about its status.

Comment: Thanks for the code change advice, I'll try to integrate the relevant changes. Well, I was using NodeJS 6.9.5 but the target has 4.4.3 and until that changes, I'm obliged to use this old version and due to resource constraints at this point, it is not possible to have a new version for the target.

Comment: I read the documentation on kill(), it is not clear to me if it will make the process exit cleanly. By explanation it seems to internally do the same thing as disconnect and exit. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer the timer story in your question. I was assuming that disconnect would probably take some time and then it could be killed with a certain delay. Is it wrong?

Comment: Kill is almost definitely different, based on the underlying signal involved. A process.exit should attempt clean-up of resources (like open sockets, any connections that can respond to a terminate signal etc). Kill doesn't wait. It simply terminates the process. This is similar to sending a **kill -9 <process-ID>** in a Linux terminal.

Comment: If your goal is to deal with unresponsive child processes, then your timed kill approach is reasonable since the process is *already unresponsive* and so there is no guarantee that any clean up will occur anyway.

Comment: @SylonZero The approach is clear now. I've implemented a timer based kill. I've upvoted your response but I don't have enough points, so SO doesn't display that. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: no problem. If you think it helped answer your question, mark it as an answer. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

1. When using ES6 code with Node, it's important that you are using at least Node v6.x (or higher). This is because ES6 support is not great below that version - an up-to-date reference is here: http://node.green.
2. Working Code sample below with a few additional suggestions (and I've recommended leaving out some redundant events).
3. I would also recommend using an IDE for JS with a good linter (like WebStorm or VS Code) - there were a few syntax issues with the code (like the var decl at the top).

   ```
   var cluster = require('cluster'),
       clients = 0,  // tracks number of active clients
       workers = 3;  // configuration for number of worker tasks

   /*
    * Code to perform cluster process management.
    */
   if (cluster.isMaster) {
       // create the workers.
       // Use env variables to dictate client or worker
       for (var i = 0; i < workers; i++) {
           cluster.fork({"TYPE": 'worker'});
       }

       // Log that worker process has started
       cluster.on('online', function (worker) {
           clients++;
           console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online.');
           console.log('number of clients: ' + clients);
       });


       // TODO This doesn't seem to be an event anymore...outdated doc reference?
       /*// Detect the death of a worker and log it
       var deadWorkers = 0; // tracks dead worker tasks
       cluster.on('death', function (worker) {
           deadWorkers++;
           console.log('worker ' + worker.pid + ' died.');

           console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died.');

           if (deadWorkers === workers) {
               console.log('Server is exiting as all workers are dead.');
               process.exit(0)
           }
       });*/

       // Keep a track of clients connecting and disconnecting
       var deadClients = 0; // tracks number of dead clients
       cluster.on('disconnect', function (worker) {
           deadClients++;
           console.log('worker ' + worker.pid + ' disconnected.');
           console.log('number of dead clients: ' + clients);

           console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' disconnected.');

           // TODO It might be worth actually spawning a new child to keep the process alive
           // rather than just existing because all clients are dead.
           if (deadClients === clients) {
               console.log('Server is exiting as all clients are dead.');
               process.exit(0);
           }
       });

       // TODO Not necessary and out-of-date possibly - replaced by the online event above
       /*cluster.on('connect', function(worker)
       {
           clients++;
           console.log('number of clients: ' + clients);
       });*/

       cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
           deadWorkers++;

           console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' exited with signal: ' + signal);

           if (deadWorkers === workers) {
               console.log('Server is exiting as all clients are dead.');
               process.exit(0)
           }
       });

       // start the server task
       try {
           serverTask();
       }
       catch (err) {
           console.log("caught exception launching server task: " + err);
       }
   } else {
       try {
           workerTask();
       }
       catch (err) {
           console.log("caught exception launching worker task when cluster is not a master: " + err);
       }

       if (cluster.isWorker) {
           process.on('message', function(msg)
           {
               console.log('worker received: ' + msg);

               if ('shutdown' === msg) {
                   var pid = process.pid;
                   console.log('Worker ' + pid + ' is exiting...');

                   // TODO again, this is un-necessary
                   // process.disconnect();

                   process.exit(0);
               }
           });
       }
   }

   function serverTask() {
       console.log("server task")
   }


   function workerTask() {
       console.log("worker task")
   }


   process.on('SIGINT', function () {
       handleSignal('SIGINT');
   });


   function handleSignal(signal) {

       if (cluster.isMaster) {
           console.log("terminating due to signal: " + signal);
           console.log('Killing all workers');

           for (var i in cluster.workers) {
               cluster.workers[i].send('shutdown');

               // TODO There is no need to disconnect workers manually
               //cluster.workers[i].disconnect();

               setTimeout(function() {
                   cluster.workers[i].kill();
               }, 2000);
           }

           process.exit(signal);
       }
   }
   ```